# Adjusting Image Size with CSS For Mobile Website

Tags: html, css, image

I am having trouble adjusting images in blog articles in mobile theme. Somehow they are messing up the layout. I use the following code for images in articles.

```
<div class="leftbox">
    <img src=".mysite.net/blog/media/Photo/Indian_tourists.jpg" width="400" height="267" alt="Indian tourists" title="Indian tourists" />
</div>

<div style="text-align: center">
    <img src="mysite.net/blog/media/Mayank/Surfing_in_France.jpg" width="520" height="347" alt="Surfing in France" title="Surfing in France" />
</div>
```

I have added these codes to ensure that images don't alter the width, but it seems they are not working.

```
.post_content img {
    height: auto !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
}


.leftbox img {
    height: auto !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

This is example of a link where image would stretch on mobile devices - http://www.easydestination.net/blog/item/surfing-holidays-in-france

Comment: Can you add your code in plunker or similar place ?

Comment: By code you mean CSS file? And sorry I don't know what plunker is.

Comment: That entire site doesn't seem to be responsive.

Comment: Actually the blog software uses different theme for mobile site and redirect users to it.

Comment: That's a shame. You're going to have many viewport sizes with a possible broken layouot.

Comment: What a weird site, it does not respond to viewport resize on the fly. Or when reloading page with a smaller viewport.

Comment: Why you think this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the height/width declarations in the in-line code.

```html
<div class="leftbox"><img
src=".mysite.net/blog/media/Photo/Indian_tourists.jpg" alt="Indian tourists" title="Indian tourists" /></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the blog software add these declarations. I would have to manually remove them but then there are more than 3000 articles. It would take forever.

Comment: `$('div#someDiv').css("height", null)` - Do this for both Height&Width

Comment: Sorry but where should I add it? In the CSS file?

Comment: I don't think there is any JavaScript file

Answer (score 0):

You need to override both dimensions with your css.

```css
img {
      width: auto!important;
      height: auto!important;
      max-width: 100%!important;
      max-height: 100%!important;
    }
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/900x500" width="900" height="500" />
```

Comment: I added you img code to CSS file. Now its a weird problem. Some pages are working fine in Opera mini but not on dolphin. While its working completely fine on ucbrowser mini.

Comment: You'll probably have to be more specific with your selector. `img` will select all images.

Comment: Should I use post_content img since the article is inside it.

Comment: I made changes to ensure that only images in articles are selected. Still its same on my phone. Working in ucmini but not on opera mini. Could you check from your phone?

Comment: I have a Windows phone from which it will work. If there are limitations within the rendering engine on Opera Mini there is little you can do other than remove the height/width attributes from the output.